# pandas -- how to select by column values faster

Tags: python, pandas

I have to do something similar to below. where I iterate through a list of dates

But that process is slow because each time I iterate by `dfday = df[df.Date=d]` I went through a whole data frame to do the boolean masking.

Is there a way to make it faster?

```
df = pd.read_csv('bt.csv', sep='\t')          
dates = df.Date.unique()

for d in dates:
    dfday = df[df.Date=d]
    # do something
```

Comment: depending on what you want to do exactly , you can play around with `df.groupby('Date'`) or any other vectorized way using the dataframe itself `df[df.Date=d]`, iterating a dataframe is not always (disclaimer) the best option, but really an mcve would help :) Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby('Date').apply(#do something)`